# Storing a number bigger than the integer limit in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

Let me explain my problem with an example.
I have two variables 
     a=74686 and b=20930625.
I want to store 
     c= (a x 2^16) + b. 
This exceeds the integer limit(32bits) in vhdl. 
It is okay for me to store c in two separate registers say c1 and c2, and tell users to concatenate bits of c1 and c2 to get the actual result. i.e I want to store lower 32 bits of c in c1 and remaining bits in c2.
How can I do this?

Comment: Have you considered using the `unsigned` type from the `numeric_std` library?
You should add a minimum complete verifyable example.

Comment: Don't think in programming way. Integer is only helper type, for example for counters. For your purpose, you should use register with proper length. You can do it for example with signal with unsigned type, as JHBonarius said.

Comment: @Staszek I totally disagree with your statement. Even if it is not true in this specific case, integer types are in many cases much more interesting than vector types (accurate ranges with better error detection in simulation, faster simulation...) And they are perfectly synthesizable. VHDL is a *high* level hardware description language.

Comment: @JHBonarius `numeric_std` is not a library. It is a package of the `ieee` library. But your are right, of course, using `ieee.numeric_std.unsigned` is probably the best choice.

Comment: Dumb me! Thank you @JHBonarius  for the suggestion. I had excluded unsigned from consideration.